# Stuck with target age group in Google Play console complaining about location permissions

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-play-console

I'm dealing with the error displayed in the screenshot below: "You must remove the request for location permissions from your app if your target audience only includes children under the age of 13." To note, my audience selection is accurate. Google asked me to change the audience (it included adults too) otherwise the app gets rejected.

[image]

Here's the permissions my app is asking for. Thing to note: they are  the same across all my older bundles and release tracks.

[image]

Here's the permissions array in my Expo-based app.config.js.

[image]

I've already reached out to Google support, but who knows how long they'll take to get back. Anyone else out there wrestle with a similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was originating from the `expo-media-library`. It was adding the `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` permission which turned out to be the root cause of the issue. In order to resolve this, I had to remove the library and any functionality dependent on it. Doing so successfully resolved the issue.